# Why do I get an error related to a controller when I created a custom module?

Tags: views, 8, routes, page-controller

I created custom module following the *Creating a custom module on Drupal* tutorial.

The teacher of this tutorial demonstrated how you can create a custom module that displays on the page `Hello world`. But I have a slightly more difficult task. I need to create a custom module that will display the weather on the page, receiving data using API, like this.

**17.52

1016

London**

#### What I did.

I created the weather.info.yml file.

```
name: Weather module              
description: Weather module 
core: 8.x                               
type: module                        
package: Weather
```

I created the weather.routing.yml file.

```
weather.weather_page:                               
  path: '/weather'
  defaults:                                                       
    _controller: '\Drupal\weather\Controller\WeatherPage::getWeather'                          
  requirements:                                        
     _permission: 'access content'
```

In src/Controller, I created the WeatherPage.php file.

```php
namespace Drupal\weather\Controller;        

class WeatherPage
{
  public function getWeather($city)
  {
    $response = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='.$city.',uk&appid=32ae008b1c7259324aa50450687fabf5&units=metric');
    $jsn = json_decode($response);
    
    echo $jsn->main->temp; 
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo $jsn->main->pressure; 
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo $city; 
    
  }    
}

$class = new WeatherPage();
$class->getWeather('London');


?>
```

I get an error related to the controller.

> [image]

How do I fix this error?

P.S. One forum user writes that the problem may be due to:

- The controller must return the array
- No code should be behind the class

I'm a Drupal newbie.

Comment: You are assuming the call to getWeather comes from within your class, where you are providing it with 'London'. However that function is also called from the route file, where you do not provide a value for `city`. Please clarify where the city should come from. Will you provide it from url, user profile, etc?

Comment: @Neograph734 One forum user writes that the problem may be due to:
1) the controller must return the array
2) no code should be behind the class

But I'm a newcomer to drupal. And php I do not know at all.

Comment: Drupal is a bit difficult to get into, and since Drupal 8 there is much more smaller files all doing their specific parts. Rather than clicking along with a tutorial (which can be a great start) try to look up the relevant documentation to actually understand what is happening. In this case The [routing system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system) and specifically the section _Parameters in routes_.

Comment: To fully stick with Drupal standards it would indeed be better to have the controller return a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/render-api/render-arrays) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the parameter to the path. Change this:

```
path: '/weather'
```

To this:

```
path: '/weather/{city}'
```

Note that the parameter name `{city}` must be expressed as the parameter `$city` in your callback (which you've done). If you for exampled changed the function definition to `getWeather($c)`, you would get an error.

Also, you need to remove this code:

```
$class = new WeatherPage();
$class->getWeather('London');


?>
```

And finally, you'll need to return a render array. Change this:

```
echo $jsn->main->temp;
```

To this:

```
return [
  '#markup' => $jsn->main->temp,
];
```

Comment: When I wrote as you advised:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/a798a59ca6461d27efaa8e4ee4846dbc/1592593871/100634/1372209/Screenshot_8.png

I get error:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/a8911222b1a7b1d6806171a5bbc9cd89/1592593982/46586/1372209/59615Screenshot_9.png
Maybe I misunderstood something? Then please write in more detail in the answer

Comment: You need to clear the Drupal cache after making any changes to routing files.

Comment: Also, `{London}` needs to be `{city}`. Then you will visit the path `/weather/London` to get London weather.

Comment: This is also covered in the docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example and https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes

Comment: thanks it works! But I need also display on page `$jsn->main->pressure;` and `$jsn->main->humidity` and `$jsn->name`. How to add to this code another fields from API response:
`return [
  '#markup' => $jsn->main->temp,
];` ? I simply have bad knowlege in php

Comment: You need to return a better render array instead of just markup, one with your desired items and fed to a theme function.

Comment: The formatting of your render array is a new question. This one was about the error accessing your Controller, which has been answered.